# Create a view that partially blurs Theme.Wallpaper

Tags: java, android, view

I am trying to create a **custom view** that blurs the wallpaper below given by the style **Theme.Wallpaper**.

Just like Apple's Home screen

[image]

The libraries I tried could only blur an imageview behind the blur view.
Is there a way to do it like the image given?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/500px/500px-android-blur

Comment: With this library i need to set a blurred view, but what's Theme.Wallpaper's view in order to blur the wallpaper?